# Does everyone choose their reactions to Galactic Events in Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

When there's an event in *Endless Space*, I get to choose how I react to it. For at least "Galactic Events", are all empires in the galaxy choosing their reactions to it at the same time?

What about the other event types?

Answer (score 3):

All players (including AI) will pick their action on the same turn for Interactive Global Events. The impact of choices is then applied the following turn.

Narrative Interactive Events are triggered for players independently (e.g. when you colonize a specific planet) and will not usually be interacted with at the same time.

Check event types on [this wiki](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Events)